# Vuelidate 2 validated array fields show errors initially even though they haven't been touched

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, vuelidate

I am working on upgrading `Vue 2` to `Vue 3` and I have installed the next version of `vuelidate` and I am trying to validate dynamic array of fields, however each time I add a new item to the array it shows an initial error. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is my code, first `setup` method:

```
setup () {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() }
},
```

inside `validations`:

```
currentUser: {
    alarm_emails: {
        $each: helpers.forEach({
            alarm_email: {
                required,
                email,
                maxLength: maxLength(64),
            }
        })
    },
}
```

and here is the part of the template responsible for the emails:

```
<div class='sm-12'>
    <div 
        v-for="(email,k) in currentUser.alarm_emails" :key="k"
        :class="{ disabled: !email.is_alarm && !currentUser.is_email_alarm}"
        class='custom-input sm-12 emailInput additional'
    >
        <input 
            type='email' 
            class=' icon-e-mail' 
            v-model="currentUser.alarm_emails[k].alarm_email" 
            @input="clearErrors('emails.' + k + '.alarm_email')" />
        
        <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            :id="`email${k}`" 
            :name="k"
            :checked="email.is_alarm"
            @input="email.is_alarm = !!$event.target.checked">

        <label :for="`email${k}`" />
        <i class='icon-bin' @click="removeEmailField(k)" />

        <input-error 
            v-if="errors['emails.' + k + '.alarm_email'] || v$.currentUser.alarm_emails.$each.$response.$errors[k] ? v$.currentUser.alarm_emails.$each.$response.$errors[k].alarm_email : false" 
            :errors="errors['emails.' + k + '.alarm_email'] ? errors['emails.' + k + '.alarm_email'] : false"
            :vuelidate="v$.currentUser.alarm_emails.$each.$response.$errors[k] ? v$.currentUser.alarm_emails.$each.$response.$errors[k].alarm_email : false" 
        />  
    </div>

    <i class='icon-plus increment-btn' @click="addEmailField()" />
</div>
```

and here is my `addEmailField`:

```
addEmailField() {
    this.currentUser.alarm_emails.push({alarm_email: '', is_alarm: this.currentUser.is_email_alarm });
},
```